adding a new column to a dataframe with a function and condition
I used the below code;
def my_function(price_label):
    for index, line in df.iterrows():
        if df['Price'] <= 15000:
            return "Low"
        elif df['Price'] > 15000 and df['Price'] <= 38000:
            return "Average"
        elif df['Price'] > 38000:
            return "High"

# Add a new column 'Price Status' based on values from other columns
df['Price Label'] = df['Price'].apply(my_function)
df

I got this error message;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22476\186094663.py", line 11, in <module>
    df['Price Status'] = df['Price'].apply(my_function)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4904, in apply
    ).apply()
      ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1427, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1507, in apply_standard
    mapped = obj._map_values(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 921, in _map_values
    return algorithms.map_array(arr, mapper, na_action=na_action, convert=convert)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 1743, in map_array
    return lib.map_infer(values, mapper, convert=convert)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "lib.pyx", line 2972, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22476\186094663.py", line 3, in my_function
    if df['Price'] <= 15000:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1576, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2144, in showtraceback
    stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1448, in structured_traceback
    return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1339, in structured_traceback
    return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1186, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1076, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    self.get_records(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset) if etb else []
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1168, in get_records
    FrameInfo(
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 780, in __init__
    ix = inspect.getsourcelines(frame)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 1264, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\boni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\inspect.py", line 1093, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code

what could be causing this?

Note: The answer by Serge de Gosson de Varennes fixes the issue with your initial approach. That said, it is much better to use vectorization instead of df.apply or (worse) df.iterrows. Cf. the answers to this post.

Use np.select:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Price': [10000, 20000, 40000, 12000, 35000]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

condlist = [df['Price'] <= 15000,
            df['Price'] <= 38000] 

choicelist = ['Low', 
              'Average']

df['Price Label'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='High')

Output
   Price Price Label
0  10000         Low
1  20000     Average
2  40000        High
3  12000         Low
4  35000     Average

Performance comparison
np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility

data = {
    'Price': np.random.randint(low=0, high=60_000, size=1_000_000)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

%timeit np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='High')
# 47.5 µs ± 1.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit df['Price'].apply(my_function)
# 210 ms ± 15.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


Even better, using pandas.cut (see duplicate) ;)

@mozway: well, there you go, always learning :)

You cannot pass df['price']. Here is how to do this:
def my_function(price_label):
    if price_label <= 15000:
        return "Low"
    elif 15000 < price_label <= 38000:
        return "Average"
    else:
        return "High"

import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Price': [10000, 20000, 40000, 12000, 35000]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Price Label'] = df['Price'].apply(my_function)
print(df)

which gives
   Price Price Label
0  10000         Low
1  20000     Average
2  40000        High
3  12000         Low
4  35000     Average


On elif 15000 < price_label <= 38000, note that the first part, 15000 < price_label, is superfluous. Any value meeting this condition will already have been captured by if price_label <= 15000.
